How would Jews observe Shabbat on a 20-hour planet?
I'm writing a sci fi novel in which the main character finds a Jewish community living on a planet he explores. The planet has a 20 hour day and takes around 520 days to orbit the sun. How would Shabbat happen in that case? I'm guessing the Jewish calendar itself would remain unchanged in terms of the chagim. But what about Shabbat? Would Jews observe the 'full' day of Shabbat or just the 20 hours?

If the day is shorter, wouldn't Shabbat be shorter, too ?

Related https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3744/759

The length of the calendar year on Earth is 365.2425 days or 8,765.82 hours. If the days are only 20 hours, that makes the year 438.291 days not 520. Therefore, your planet is further from the Sun than the Earth and it may have a different seasonal pattern in the year with two additional seasons. Alternatively, higher rotational speed  needs to be factored with conservation of energy to calculate the exact perod of rotation.

Yes, it is further than the sun than the earth. How would the Jewish calendar be observed in this case? Would it be OK to follow it as it is now, ie with one and a bit Jewish years in the planetary year, or would extra days have to be added to eg keep Pesach in spring?

Yes - Shabbat would be shorter and I'm wondering if therefore it has to be kept according to how it is on Earth?

@rachel Keeping 24 hour long days on a 20 hour planet sounds like a crazy thing to do practically. If that's what makes your story tick then go for it, but more likely you want characters who fit in to the local system and you can go with that. This is your fictional world.

Yes, I just wanted to make sure that it would be seen as acceptable from a halachic pov?

@rachel either way would pass as plausible to most readers methinks. Any reader actually knowledgeable about Judaism would know you're just making it up.

An hour is 1/24 of day.

When on a planet in space, you must prorate the length of the day or the year.  Rabbi Azriel Rosenfeld says:  "On Mars, a “day” is 24 hours and 39 minutes in earth time and a “year” is 687 days in earth time, so you must modify observance of the calendar accordingly."

Thanks very much - I'm wondering whether  as the planet's day is shorter, whether it would be better to observe the full 24 hours, halachically speaking (I'm guessing there would be numerous Talmudic disputes on this)

Also  would extra days have to be added in between the chagim if the 'year' was longer to keep eg Passover at the same season?

Yes, extra days in between  -- I suppose that's what "prorating" means.

Thanks. According to the novel my protagonist is a jew who is not very observant, disconnected with Judaism and hated living on earth and wanted to leave. Maybe he will find himself returning to this new version of Judaism ... :D

@rachel "I'm guessing there would be numerous Talmudic disputes on this" There are not since this is just a fantasy questions. The best you'll get here is semi-educated speculation, like on Worldbuilding.SE. The goal is just to make your fiction somewhat more realistic sounding.

Yeah :) I meant that if had happened, there would be loads of disputes once they had actually got there, sorry!

I'm thinking for the prevailing (alien) culture some regions could have 7 day weeks and some could have different calendars based on one or other moons. I was thinking the average 'week' would be 9 days long with 3 weekends (making 58 weeks). The Jewish year of 7 days would be slightly longer than 74 weeks in a year with the extra days in it. Unless they decided to add extra days in the week to make it more like the prevailing culture but as these are Orthodox, they would have tried not to do that :D

"you must modify observance of the calendar accordingly" — Does that mean ignore the local conditions and stay in sync with what is happening on Earth (e.g. Jerusalem), or does it mean define a week as seven days and seven nights according to local conditions?

To clarify the point of Maurice Mizrahi, think of the rotation of your planet around the Sun to be occurring at the same angle and in the same plane as the Earth. The seasons would be determined by the angles at which the seasons change on Earth. The same should go for days. However, to correct with the Earth's calendar, you will have to introduce a double Shabbat (or double Yom tov) at some points to synchronize.
